# Haskell: Check if integer, or check type of variable

Tags: haskell

So let's say you have a variable n.

You want to check if its an integer, or even better yet check what type it is.

I know there is a function in haskell, isDigit that checks if it is a char.

However is there a function that checks if n is in integer, or even better, gives the type of n?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using an interactive Haskell prompt (like GHCi) you can type `:t <expression>` and that will give you the type of an expression.

e.g.

```
Prelude> :t 9
```

gives

```
9 :: (Num t) => t
```

or e.g.

```
Prelude> :t (+)
```

gives

```
(+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

Comment: What if you're using Intellij's Haskell plugin?

Comment: @Displee [edon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4131682/204723) seems to cover that.

Answer (score 21):

```
import Data.Typeable
isInteger :: (Typeable a) => a -> Bool
isInteger n = typeOf n == typeOf 1
```

But you should think about your code, this is not very much like Haskell should be, and it probably is not what you want.

Comment: Given that he mentioned `isDigit`, I think he wants to check whether a string represents an integer - not whether a given variable *is* an integer, even though that's what the title said. Also your type signature is wrong: you're missing the `Typeable` constraint.

Comment: This is almost always a wrong approach. It looks like the poster is a Haskell beginner, and we should try to understand his problem better, not give solutions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [typeOf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeOf) method from the [Data.Typeable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) package for this.

```
import Data.Typeable

typeOf myVar
```

This [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CodeontheRocks.cotr-snippets) contains a few snippets to make remembering this easier (`checkType`, `getType`, `typeOf`, etc)