# getLine and is value integer

Tags: haskell

I get value using x <- getLine, how can I check that x can be interpreted as an integer number?

Comment: You don't need to, I can tell you from the comfort of my home that it is [Char]. I will edit your question so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
do x <- getLine
   case filter (\(_,s) -> s == "") (reads x :: [(Int, String)]) of
      [] -> putStrLn "x cannot be parsed as an Int"
      (xAsInt, _) : _
        -> putStrLn (concat ["x can be parsed as an Int, *and* its Int value is ",
                             show xAsInt])
```

Comment: @mrquestion: the comments were supposed to be replaced with your own code. Try running my updated version.

Comment: It works for me. What error are you getting? If you're typing it directly into ghci you will need to [use `:{` and `:}`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-stmts) so ghci knows you're giving it a multiline statement.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Data.Char.isNumber](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/3.0.2.0/doc/html/Data-Char.html#v%3AisNumber).

Answer (score 0):

[Haskell: Check if integer, or check type of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131552/haskell-check-if-integer-or-check-type-of-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `maybeIO` function that performs an `IO` action in a `catch`, returning `Just` the result of the action if successful, or `Nothing` if an exception occurred.  Then, you can use `readLn` instead of `getLine` + `reads`, with `maybeIO` to convert any exception into a `Nothing`.

```
import Control.Monad (liftM)

maybeIO :: IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
maybeIO f = catch (liftM Just f) (const $ return Nothing)

main = do
  i <- maybeIO (readLn :: IO Int)
  print i
```